# Alter table to disable trigger in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, triggers

If we have an alter table statement within a stored procedure. Will it just affect that session or will it affect all sessions?

We use the alter table to disable the triggers that occur because we don't want them run when the stored procedure occurs but want the update triggers to run at all other times.

Cheers,

Comment: I would think it will effect all sessions unless it is on a temp table.

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1591/disabling-a-trigger-for-a-specific-sql-statement-or-session/

Comment: When you have a trigger that you only want run some of the time, you should re-think that trigger.

Comment: what if you write your SPID in a table and in your trigger check the current SPID and exit the trigger if it is match with stored SPID in the other table? I Think when you are in a stored procedure, all the triggers use the same connection of that stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

"Alter table" is an DDS operation - it will change the DB structure for all connections.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trick: create temp table with unique name like `#no_triggers_for_[procname]` at the beginning of your sp and check for it's existence within triggers.